# Catching doctrine exceptions when saving entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

While digging into the exception handling of Doctrine, I stumbled on this code example that made me wonder out loud if this was overkill or could be of some use:

```
  // Save entity
        try {
            $em->persist($someEntity);
            $em->flush();

            $this->logger->info("Saved someEntity");

        } catch (DBALException $e) {
            $this->logger->addError("DBALException [{code}]: {message}",
                array('code' => $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->logger->addError("PDOException [{code}]: {message}",
                array('code' => $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()));
        } catch (ORMException $e) {
            $this->logger->addError("ORMException [{code}]: {message}",
                array('code' => $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->addError("Exception [{code}]: {message}",
                array('code' => $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()));
        }
```

I always just used the generic exception (the last in code example), and was wondering if this is overkill in most cases unless one wants to handle one of the defined exception differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that isn't an overkill because in some specific case you need to understand which error it's generate by the save of an entity.

For example if you have a problem about parameters number because you create a custom query you may wonder to know if is a `PDO` problem or a `DBAL` problem to understand where to change your code.

In many case you don't need all this exception but in other case is important to understand which part of your code fail exactly to fix the bug.

What have you posted is a rare example on how to catch an exception, but for me when you are into a very deep and complex problem is very important to understand clearly and faster which exception is generated and from which vendor / dependency / library

Comment: My thought was -  if one wants to catch and treat all exceptions in same manner, ie - log error and exit,  the generic exception catch at the end of the would suffice, am I correct?

The info of the component that threw it is still enclosed ... it seems ( if I understood correctly ) you would want to separate the catch clauses if you want to handle them differently. 

Thanks

Comment: Yeah at the end is sufficient but in terms of debugging more deeper is very useful to have different exception I think @stefgosselin